# <i> is now <em> and <b> is now <strong>; but what is <u>?

Tags: html

It is now widely preferred to use `<em>` instead of `<i>` and also `<strong>` instead of `<b>` for various reasons; the most important one being their accessibility<sup>1</sup>.

**Is there a similar equivalent for `<u>`?**

**Related:**

- [Why is <u> evil while <strong> and <em> is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525168/why-is-u-evil-while-strong-and-em-is-not)

<sup>1. When a text-reader comes along text marked with `<i>` it does not *read* it with an emphasis unlike `<em>` and likewise for `<b>` and `<strong>`; they are merely *displayed* with emphasis.</sup>

Comment: Underlined text is presentational, `<u>` has no semantic meaning. `<strong>` (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) and `<em>` (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element) do have semantic meaning, how they look presentationally is totally up to you.

Comment: The question asks for an “equivalent for `<u>`” without specifying what that might mean—and the question seems to be based on a wrong assumption about `<em>` and `<strong>` being equivalents for other elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't one. `em` and `strong` aren't replacements for `i` and `b`; they are supposed to be used in different contexts. (See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/271776/436282)

Although it's true that using `<u>` is somewhat archaic (though still acceptable); it's best to use `text-decoration: underline` in your CSS instead.

Comment: `<u>` is *not* outdated according to HTML5 CR, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-u-element

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd use either `<strong>` or `<em>` and then CSS to style it to display it underlined.